# SchemaCrawler Code to produce a simple .dot file

Tags: schemacrawler

I would like produce a file which contains pairs of tables; a master on the left and a detail on the right or said another way parent and child.

In the article: "How to Visualize Your SQLite Database with One Command" using --output-file=output.png probably has some intermediate files that are used by GraphViz to provide the data. And for me a simple .dot file would be just fine. digraph Net {"Population" -> "deaths" "Population" -> "births" }  What is the code necessary to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It is quite easy to do this kind of customization with SchemaCrawler and a little bit of Python scripting. Take a look at [How to Generate Mermaid Diagrams for Your Database](https://dev.to/sualeh/how-to-generate-mermaid-diagrams-for-your-database-33bn). If you tweak the Python script in that article, it will generate the graph that you would like to have.

```py
from schemacrawler.schema import TableRelationshipType # pylint: disable=import-error

print('digraph Net {')
for table in catalog.tables:
  for childTable in table.getRelatedTables(TableRelationshipType.child):
    print('  "' + table.fullName + '" -> "' + childTable.fullName + '"')
print('}')
```

Sualeh Fatehi, [SchemaCrawler](https://www.schemacrawler.com/)